# Nested form shows too many fields! Rails Beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I as Rails Beginner created an simple demo app to experiment with nested forms. 
But somehow my code shows strange byproducts:

[image]

My only aim was to create new treatments for patients on the patients show page, and now
it show input fields with yet created treatments and some other crazy stuff!! What did i wrong? My steps so far:

```
rails new hama

cd hama

rails g scaffold Patient name:string

rails g model Treatment content:string

rake db:migrate
```

Patient model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :treatments_attributes
has_many :treatments, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :treatments
```

Treatment model:

```
attr_accessible :content
belongs_to :patient
```

In patient/show:

```
 <b>Name:</b>
 <%= @patient.name %>
 </p>

 <p>
 <b>Treatments:</b>
 <%= @patient.treatments.each do |treatment| %>
   <%= treatment.content %>
 <% end %>
 </p>

 <%= form_for @patient do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :treatments do |ff| %>
     <%= ff.text_field :content %>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.fields_for :treatments do |ff| %>
     <%= ff.text_field :content %>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

And in Patient controller:

```
  def show
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    treatment = @patient.treatments.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @patient }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about where it shows all the internals of your Treatment objects?

Change this:

```
<%= @patient.treatments.each do |treatment| %>
```

to this:

```
<% @patient.treatments.each do |treatment| %>
```

Using `<%= %>`, with the `=`, means to output the result of that Ruby line on to the page. Without it, it's just code that Ruby runs.

Comment: And why does it show input fields with yet created treatments? I only want  two input fields for new treatments

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should remove the `=` from this line:

```
<%= @patient.treatments.each do |treatment| %>
```

You don't want to display the output of the `each`. The loop contents provide the output. Just use:

```
<% @patient.treatments.each do |treatment| %>
```

All the other fields are output since that's what your code asks for. This part of your code is showing all of the same fields twice:

```
<%= f.fields_for :treatments do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.text_field :content %>
<% end %>

<%= f.fields_for :treatments do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.text_field :content %>
<% end %>
```

If there are two specific input fields for a treatment, then there needs to be two different attributes.

Comment: only two input fields for new treatments! Thank you

Comment: @EmSta I updated my answer accordingly. Your code is asking for all treatment attributes twice. If you have two specific inputs for each treatment that you want, then they each need their own attribute name.

Comment: the thing is that at the time I can update treatments but  I dont want this. My aim was to create two treatments with only have to click  once an submit button

Comment: @EmSta sounds like you need at least two separate treatment attributes, or allow the user to enter (free-form) multiple treatments into a single text field. Either way, they can be saved with a single submit click.

Comment: Sorry but can you give me an example for treatment attributes?

Comment: Really what's needed is a description/example from you on how you want it to work, then the rest can be sorted out. You indicated you needed two input fields for treatments, so I'm just saying that means two different treatment attributes. Their contents/type are totally up to you and how you want your app to work.

Comment: Sorry @mbratch but i dont think your right, i made it work with the nested attributes, in another controller! But thanks again!

Comment: @EmSta I don't doubt you got something working in another controller. I probably am not understanding the problem correctly. I was only seeking additional information.